# CMake generating .sln files and other VS files

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new to learning CMake, and as I am going through tutorials, I am running the command Cmake -S -B, but instead of creating a makefile, it is making lots of vcxproj files and a Project.sln.
From what i understnand, cmake can make VS files, but I want it to just make Makefiles. How do I get it back?

Comment: Type `cmake --help` in your terminal / cmd.exe and press enter and it will list the available generators for the version of CMake you have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `"Unix Makefiles"` to variable `CMAKE_GENERATOR`